# How to get request body in Symfony routing

Tags: php, symfony4

I am using Symfony Routing Component outside framework.

This is how I am matching the routes

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

$routes = (new YamlFileLoader(new FileLocator([__DIR__])))->load("routes.yaml");

$context = new RequestContext();
$context->fromRequest(Request::createFromGlobals());

$parameters = (new UrlMatcher($routes, $context))->match($context->getPathInfo());
print_r($parameters);
```

I am able to match the route and _controller here. But I cannot find a way to get the request body from the RouteContext object.

I know that I can get the request body from the Request Object of HttpFoundation. But since we are setting the RequestContext from Request::createFromGlobals, I am presuming that there should be a way to get those request parameters as well.

Thanks

Comment: Dude you already have the request. You created one and passed it to the context. Could you explain what are you trying to accomplish? Router’s only responsibility is to resolve a controller based on the request.

Comment: So with this component I have reach to the point where I know which controller is supposed to be called. Now the controller has a function that needs certain parameters that are supposed to be extracted from the Request object.

My concern is to not use both RequestContext and Request separately.

Comment: Have you checked request’s parameters bag?